# Как исправить баг в морфинге svg?

Tags: html, css, svg

кто силен в svg помогите пожалуйста исправить баг. 
https://jsfiddle.net/n19L2tam/10/
я уже пытался по разному исправить, и новый текст делал, и заменял текст изображением, но все равно в самом конце морфинга отображается глючно(последняя буква). Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть причина, или в каком направлении копать что бы исправить баг.
Может ли быть причина в том что я из нескольких путей сделал один большой путь?

```js
var svg = document.getElementById("cups");
var s = Snap(svg);

var simpleCup = Snap.select('#simple-cup');
var fancyCup = Snap.select('#fancy-cup');

var simpleCupPoints = simpleCup.node.getAttribute('d');
var fancyCupPoints = fancyCup.node.getAttribute('d');


var toFancy = function(){
 setTimeout(function () {
  simpleCup.animate({ d: fancyCupPoints }, 4000, mina.backout, toSimple);
  },2000);  
}

var toSimple = function(){
 setTimeout(function () {
  simpleCup.animate({ d: simpleCupPoints }, 4000, mina.backout, toFancy);
  },2000); 
}


// toSimple();
toFancy();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>

<svg style="overflow:visible;" id="cups" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="50pt" height="50pt" viewBox="0 0 50 50" version="1.1">
<path id="simple-cup" d="M 46.796875 10.960938 C 46.835938 10.84375 46.875 10.804688 46.875 10.648438 C 46.875 9.980469 46.367188 9.550781 45.703125 9.550781 L 42.96875 9.550781 C 42.304688 9.550781 41.796875 10.058594 41.796875 10.726562 C 41.796875 10.882812 41.835938 10.726562 41.875 11.117188 L 36.289062 11.117188 L 34.570312 7.597656 C 33.945312 6.304688 32.265625 5.25 30.859375 5.25 L 19.140625 5.25 C 17.695312 5.25 16.054688 6.304688 15.429688 7.597656 L 13.710938 11.117188 L 12.109375 11.117188 L 12.109375 9.355469 C 12.109375 9.121094 11.953125 9.160156 11.71875 9.160156 L 3.90625 9.160156 C 3.671875 9.160156 3.515625 9.121094 3.515625 9.355469 L 3.515625 10.921875 C 1.5625 10.921875 0 12.484375 0 14.441406 L 0 41.035156 C 0 42.992188 1.5625 44.75 3.515625 44.75 L 46.484375 44.75 C 48.4375 44.75 50 42.992188 50 41.035156 L 50 14.441406 C 50 12.640625 48.59375 11.117188 46.796875 10.960938 Z M 18.75 8.808594 C 18.75 8.574219 18.90625 8.417969 19.140625 8.417969 L 30.859375 8.417969 C 31.09375 8.417969 31.25 8.574219 31.25 8.808594 L 31.25 10.371094 C 31.25 10.605469 31.09375 10.765625 30.859375 10.765625 L 19.140625 10.765625 C 18.90625 10.765625 18.75 10.605469 18.75 10.371094 Z M 5.46875 18.78125 C 4.179688 18.78125 3.125 17.726562 3.125 16.433594 C 3.125 15.144531 4.179688 14.089844 5.46875 14.089844 C 6.757812 14.089844 7.8125 15.144531 7.8125 16.433594 C 7.8125 17.726562 6.757812 18.78125 5.46875 18.78125 Z M 8.59375 20.738281 C 7.929688 20.738281 7.421875 20.226562 7.421875 19.5625 C 7.421875 18.898438 7.929688 18.390625 8.59375 18.390625 C 9.257812 18.390625 9.765625 18.898438 9.765625 19.5625 C 9.765625 20.230469 9.257812 20.738281 8.59375 20.738281 Z M 25 41.464844 C 17.460938 41.464844 11.328125 35.324219 11.328125 27.777344 C 11.328125 20.226562 17.460938 14.089844 25 14.089844 C 32.539062 14.089844 38.671875 20.226562 38.671875 27.777344 C 38.671875 35.324219 32.539062 41.464844 25 41.464844 Z M 25 16.824219 C 18.984375 16.824219 14.0625 21.753906 14.0625 27.777344 C 14.0625 33.800781 18.984375 38.726562 25 38.726562 C 31.015625 38.726562 35.9375 33.800781 35.9375 27.777344 C 35.9375 21.753906 31.015625 16.824219 25 16.824219 Z M 25 33.644531 C 21.757812 33.644531 19.140625 31.023438 19.140625 27.777344 C 19.140625 24.53125 21.757812 21.910156 25 21.910156 C 28.242188 21.910156 30.859375 24.53125 30.859375 27.777344 C 30.859375 31.023438 28.242188 33.644531 25 33.644531 Z M 25 33.644531 "/>
</svg>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
<svg id="cups" width="210mm" height="297mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 210 297" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
 <metadata>
  <rdf:RDF>
   <cc:Work rdf:about="">
    <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
    <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/>
    <dc:title/>
   </cc:Work>
  </rdf:RDF>
 </metadata>
 <g style="font-feature-settings:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal" aria-label="ПЕТР ИВАНОВ">
  <path id="fancy-cup" d="m193.99 8.8955q0 1.9191-1.3547 3.3189-1.3547 1.3772-3.9511 1.9868 1.3998 0.38382 2.1223 1.2644 0.72249 0.85796 0.72249 1.9868 0 1.7836-1.1289 3.0932-1.1063 1.3095-3.2512 2.032-2.1449 0.69991-5.1703 0.69991-1.1289 0-1.8062-0.06773-0.0226 0.63218-0.54187 0.94827-0.51929 0.31609-1.3321 0.31609t-1.1289-0.36124q-0.29351-0.36124-0.24835-1.0612 0.2032-3.1609 0.79022-6.6153 0.58702-3.477 1.4901-6.7056 0.15805-0.56444 0.63218-0.79022 0.47413-0.22578 1.2418-0.22578 1.3772 0 1.3772 0.76764 0 0.31609-0.13547 0.72249-0.58702 1.7611-1.174 4.7865-0.58702 3.0028-0.83538 5.7348 1.0837 0.09031 1.7611 0.09031 3.1609 0 4.6284-0.90311 1.4901-0.92569 1.4901-2.3481 0-0.99342-0.85796-1.6708-0.83538-0.67733-2.8222-0.74507-0.45156-0.02258-0.63218-0.22578-0.18062-0.2032-0.18062-0.65476 0-0.65476 0.27093-1.0612 0.27094-0.4064 0.99342-0.42898 1.603-0.04516 2.89-0.47413 1.3095-0.42898 2.0546-1.1966 0.74506-0.79022 0.74506-1.8288 0-1.3095-1.2869-2.0546-1.2869-0.76764-3.9511-0.76764-2.4158 0-4.6736 0.63218-2.2578 0.6096-3.8382 1.5579-0.72249 0.42898-1.2192 0.42898-0.4064 0-0.63218-0.27093-0.2032-0.29351-0.2032-0.72249 0-0.56444 0.22578-0.97084 0.24835-0.4064 1.1515-0.92569 1.8965-1.0837 4.4478-1.6933t5.2155-0.6096q4.0866 0 6.096 1.3772 2.0094 1.3772 2.0094 3.635zm-29.451 14.563q-2.0094 0-3.635-0.90311-1.603-0.90311-2.5513-2.6416-0.94827-1.7611-0.94827-4.1995 0-3.4318 1.2418-6.0508 1.2644-2.619 3.4092-4.0414 2.1675-1.4224 4.7865-1.4224 2.0094 0 3.6124 0.90311 1.6256 0.90311 2.5739 2.6642 0.94827 1.7385 0.94827 4.1769 0 3.4318-1.2644 6.0508-1.2418 2.619-3.4092 4.0414-2.1449 1.4224-4.7639 1.4224zm0.22578-2.6642q1.7611 0 3.0932-1.0837 1.3547-1.0837 2.0772-3.0028 0.72249-1.9417 0.72249-4.3801 0-2.6868-1.1289-4.064-1.1289-1.3998-2.9125-1.3998-1.7385 0-3.0706 1.0837-1.3321 1.0612-2.0772 3.0028-0.74507 1.9191-0.74507 4.3801 0 2.6868 1.1289 4.0866 1.1289 1.3772 2.9125 1.3772zm-6.526-2.4836q0.29351 0 0.45156 0.27093 0.18062 0.27093 0.18062 0.74507 0 0.88053-0.42898 1.3998-2.2352 2.7319-4.7639 2.7319-2.19 0-3.4996-1.6933-1.3095-1.6933-1.3095-4.8542 0-0.76764 0.0677-1.5353-1.4901 0.27093-3.2512 0.4064-1.174 0.09031-1.603 0.11289-0.45155 2.3029-1.2644 5.6444-0.47413 1.9643-1.8062 1.9643-1.445 0-1.445-1.3095 0-0.29351 0.11289-0.8128 0.76764-3.0932 1.2192-5.238l-1.0837 0.04516q-0.74506 0-1.0837-0.24836-0.33867-0.27093-0.33867-0.85796 0-0.74507 0.42898-1.0837 0.42898-0.36124 1.4224-0.4064l1.1966-0.04516q0.58703-3.1835 0.58703-4.8542 0-1.0612-0.31609-1.445t-0.83538-0.38382q-1.5804 0-3.5673 2.6416-0.29351 0.38382-0.65475 0.38382-0.31609 0-0.54187-0.29351t-0.22578-0.74507q0-0.69991 0.56445-1.4901 0.99342-1.3772 2.5061-2.2578 1.5127-0.90311 3.0706-0.90311 1.4676 0 2.2578 1.016 0.8128 0.99342 0.8128 3.1157 0 1.874-0.54186 5.08l2.2126-0.11289q1.4224-0.06773 2.4384-0.22578 0.4064-2.4836 1.2418-4.651 0.83538-2.1675 2.0772-3.5221 1.2418-1.3547 2.7771-1.3547 1.1289 0 1.7836 0.90311 0.65476 0.88053 0.65476 2.3255 0 5.5993-5.7122 7.7668-0.0677 0.90311-0.0677 1.874 0 2.3707 0.58702 3.3641t1.6482 0.99342q0.92569 0 1.6933-0.47413 0.76765-0.49671 1.7385-1.6708 0.27093-0.31609 0.6096-0.31609zm-3.048-12.802q-0.49671 0-1.0612 0.90311-0.54187 0.90311-1.0386 2.461t-0.79022 3.4092q1.8062-0.74507 2.6642-2.1223 0.85796-1.3772 0.85796-3.5447 0-0.51929-0.18062-0.8128-0.18063-0.29351-0.45156-0.29351zm-29.897 17.949q-1.5579 0-2.8222-0.76764-1.2418-0.76764-1.9643-2.2126-0.72249-1.4676-0.72249-3.4544 0-3.4318 1.4676-6.3444 1.4676-2.9351 4.3349-4.6962 2.8674-1.7836 6.8862-1.7836 1.0386 0 2.2126 0.15804 1.1966 0.15804 2.1675 0.47413 0.63218 0.18062 0.63218 0.90311 0 0.58702-0.45156 1.1063-0.42897 0.51929-1.016 0.51929-0.18062 0-0.27093-0.022578-1.174-0.27093-2.0094-0.38382-0.83538-0.13547-1.7611-0.13547-2.8674 0-4.8768 1.3998-2.0094 1.3772-3.0028 3.6576-0.99342 2.2804-0.99342 4.922 0 1.9191 0.74506 2.9803 0.76765 1.0386 1.9868 1.0386 1.3772 0 2.4158-1.1289t1.8965-3.6576q0.85796-2.5287 1.6933-6.8636 0.13546-0.63218 0.54186-0.85796 0.4064-0.22578 1.0837-0.22578 1.603 0 1.603 1.0386 0 0.18062-0.0677 0.45156-0.58702 2.19-1.0837 4.8542-0.47413 2.6416-0.47413 4.0188 0 1.2192 0.36124 1.7836 0.36125 0.54187 1.1063 0.54187 0.72249 0 1.3772-0.47413 0.65475-0.49671 1.6482-1.6708 0.27093-0.31609 0.6096-0.31609 0.29351 0 0.45155 0.27093 0.18062 0.27093 0.18062 0.74507 0 0.88053-0.42897 1.3998-1.1063 1.3321-2.1675 2.032-1.0612 0.69991-2.5964 0.69991-1.5804 0-2.5513-0.90311-0.97085-0.92569-1.2192-2.5964-1.6708 3.4996-4.922 3.4996zm-5.829-14.563q0 1.9191-1.3547 3.3189-1.3547 1.3772-3.9511 1.9868 1.3998 0.38382 2.1223 1.2644 0.72249 0.85796 0.72249 1.9868 0 1.7836-1.1289 3.0932-1.1063 1.3095-3.2512 2.032-2.1449 0.69991-5.1703 0.69991-1.1289 0-1.8062-0.06773-0.0226 0.63218-0.54187 0.94827-0.51929 0.31609-1.3321 0.31609t-1.1289-0.36124q-0.29351-0.36124-0.24835-1.0612 0.2032-3.1609 0.79022-6.6153 0.58702-3.477 1.4901-6.7056 0.15805-0.56444 0.63218-0.79022 0.47413-0.22578 1.2418-0.22578 1.3772 0 1.3772 0.76764 0 0.31609-0.13546 0.72249-0.58703 1.7611-1.174 4.7865-0.58702 3.0028-0.83538 5.7348 1.0837 0.09031 1.7611 0.09031 3.1609 0 4.6284-0.90311 1.4901-0.92569 1.4901-2.3481 0-0.99342-0.85796-1.6708-0.83537-0.67733-2.8222-0.74507-0.45155-0.02258-0.63218-0.22578-0.18062-0.2032-0.18062-0.65476 0-0.65476 0.27093-1.0612 0.27094-0.4064 0.99343-0.42898 1.603-0.04516 2.89-0.47413 1.3095-0.42898 2.0546-1.1966 0.74507-0.79022 0.74507-1.8288 0-1.3095-1.2869-2.0546-1.2869-0.76764-3.9511-0.76764-2.4158 0-4.6736 0.63218-2.2578 0.6096-3.8382 1.5579-0.72249 0.42898-1.2192 0.42898-0.4064 0-0.63218-0.27093-0.2032-0.29351-0.2032-0.72249 0-0.56444 0.22578-0.97084 0.24836-0.4064 1.1515-0.92569 1.8965-1.0837 4.4478-1.6933t5.2155-0.6096q4.0866 0 6.096 1.3772 2.0094 1.3772 2.0094 3.635zm-32.651 14.563q-1.8965 0-2.8674-1.0386-0.97084-1.0612-0.97084-2.8222 0-0.99342 0.29351-2.4158l1.3998-6.4572q0.04516-0.18062 0.2032-0.99342 0.18062-0.8128 0.18062-1.7611 0-0.54187-0.22578-0.8128-0.2032-0.27093-0.56444-0.27093-0.67733 0-1.5804 0.65476-0.90311 0.63218-1.8965 1.9643-0.31609 0.42898-0.69991 0.42898-0.31609 0-0.56444-0.29351-0.22578-0.31609-0.22578-0.69991 0-0.69991 0.63218-1.5804 2.3029-3.1609 5.3961-3.1609 1.3772 0 2.1449 0.83538 0.79022 0.83538 0.79022 2.461 0 1.1515-0.15804 2.1223-0.15804 0.97084-0.54187 2.6416l-0.92569 4.1317q-0.04516 0.2032-0.15804 0.72249-0.11289 0.51929-0.18062 0.99342-0.06773 0.45156-0.06773 0.90311 0 0.72249 0.4064 1.1515t1.1515 0.42898q1.3547 0 2.7319-1.445 1.3998-1.445 2.5739-4.651 1.1966-3.2286 1.8514-8.2409 0.15804-1.1515 0.45156-1.603 0.31609-0.45156 1.1966-0.45156 0.79022 0 1.174 0.47413 0.38382 0.47413 0.38382 1.5353 0 0.6096-0.15804 1.603-0.13547 0.99342-0.42898 2.7771-0.6096 3.4544-0.97084 6.3444-0.18062 1.3095-0.18062 1.9417 0 0.92569 0.4064 1.4224 0.42898 0.47413 1.1289 0.47413 0.74507 0 1.445-0.49671 0.72249-0.49671 1.6933-1.6482 0.27094-0.31609 0.6096-0.31609 0.29351 0 0.45156 0.27093 0.18062 0.27093 0.18062 0.74507 0 0.88053-0.42898 1.3998-1.174 1.4224-2.3255 2.0772-1.1515 0.65476-2.4158 0.65476-1.874 0-2.8674-0.94827-0.99342-0.97084-0.99342-2.5061 0-0.85796 0.36124-3.3415-1.1289 3.3189-2.8674 5.0574-1.7159 1.7385-3.9737 1.7385zm-13.08-13.569q0 1.9191-0.99342 3.5221-0.99342 1.603-2.89 2.619t-4.5156 1.1966l-0.97084 5.4412q-0.56444 3.1383-3.0706 3.1383-1.3772 0-2.5513-0.8128-1.1515-0.8128-1.8514-2.4836-0.69991-1.6708-0.69991-4.1092 0-4.5833 1.4676-7.7668 1.4901-3.206 3.9737-4.7865 2.5061-1.603 5.509-1.603 2.1223 0 3.5899 0.74507 1.4901 0.74507 2.2352 2.032 0.76764 1.2644 0.76764 2.8674zm-7.9925 5.0123q4.6284-0.58702 4.6284-4.8091 0-1.4901-0.99342-2.4158-0.97084-0.94827-3.0254-0.94827-2.3255 0-4.064 1.4676-1.7159 1.4676-2.6642 4.0866-0.92569 2.5964-0.92569 5.938 0 1.3998 0.27093 2.4836 0.29351 1.0837 0.72249 1.6933 0.45156 0.58702 0.85796 0.58702 0.56444 0 0.85796-1.5579l0.74507-4.2672q-0.88053-0.13547-0.76764-0.11289-0.67733-0.11289-0.88053-0.4064-0.2032-0.31609-0.2032-0.79022 0-0.49671 0.27093-0.79022 0.29351-0.29351 0.79022-0.29351 0.22578 0 0.33867 0.02258 0.54187 0.09031 0.83538 0.11289 0.29351-1.7611 0.83538-4.7188 0.13547-0.76764 0.6096-1.0837 0.49671-0.33867 1.1515-0.33867 0.74507 0 1.0612 0.29351 0.33867 0.27093 0.33867 0.88053 0 0.36124-0.04516 0.58702zm-7.3438-10.295q0.69991 0.13547 1.0386 0.47413 0.36124 0.33867 0.36124 0.79022 0 0.74507-0.42898 1.0837-0.4064 0.33867-1.3095 0.27093-2.032-0.15804-3.1835-0.2032-1.1289-0.067733-2.9803-0.090311-0.83538 4.1543-1.5353 8.3538-0.24836 1.5353-0.51929 3.5673-0.27093 2.0094-0.36124 3.2512-0.04516 0.65476-0.54187 1.016-0.49671 0.33867-1.1966 0.33867-0.74507 0-1.1515-0.36124-0.4064-0.36124-0.4064-0.94827 0-0.54187 0.15804-1.7836 0.18062-1.2644 0.4064-2.6416 0.24836-1.3772 0.38382-2.3932 0.24836-1.7159 0.56444-3.4092 0.31609-1.6933 0.63218-3.206 0.06773-0.33867 0.15804-0.76764 0.09031-0.45156 0.2032-0.99342-2.2126 0.067733-3.477 0.36124-1.2644 0.29351-1.8062 0.83538-0.51929 0.51929-0.51929 1.3547 0 0.76764 0.45156 1.4676 0.09031 0.15804 0.09031 0.33867 0 0.42898-0.51929 0.8128-0.49671 0.36124-1.0386 0.36124-0.38382 0-0.63218-0.22578-0.45156-0.38382-0.74507-1.0837-0.29351-0.72249-0.29351-1.6256 0-1.9191 1.2418-3.0706 1.2644-1.174 3.8156-1.7159 2.5739-0.54187 6.5927-0.54187 2.4836 0 3.9511 0.090311 1.4901 0.090311 2.5964 0.29351zm-17.42 14.63q0.33867-0.13547 0.56444-0.13547 0.36124 0 0.54187 0.27093t0.18062 0.69991q0 0.67733-0.33867 1.1515-0.31609 0.47413-1.1063 0.85796-1.3321 0.63218-3.4544 1.016-2.1223 0.36124-4.1769 0.36124-2.8448 0-4.7639-0.63218-1.9191-0.65476-2.8674-1.7836-0.92569-1.1289-0.92569-2.5513 0-1.9417 1.2418-3.2964 1.2644-1.3772 3.7028-1.9868-1.3321-0.38382-2.0546-1.3547-0.69991-0.97084-0.69991-2.1675 0-1.6256 1.016-2.8674 1.0386-1.2644 2.7771-1.9417 1.7385-0.67733 3.8156-0.67733 2.7996 0 4.1995 1.2192 1.3998 1.1966 1.3998 3.1157 0 1.3321-0.49671 2.1675-0.47413 0.8128-1.3772 0.8128-0.63218 0-0.99342-0.27093-0.36124-0.29351-0.36124-0.85796 0-0.38382 0.11289-0.83538 0.11289-0.74507 0.11289-1.016 0-0.8128-0.6096-1.3095-0.6096-0.51929-2.032-0.51929-1.9191 0-3.0706 0.8128t-1.1515 2.19q0 1.0612 0.85796 1.7611 0.88053 0.67733 2.8448 0.74507 0.49671 0.02258 0.69991 0.22578 0.2032 0.2032 0.2032 0.67733 0 1.4901-1.3547 1.5127-1.874 0.04515-3.1157 0.51929-1.2192 0.47413-1.7836 1.2192-0.54187 0.72249-0.54187 1.5579 0 1.3998 1.3095 2.1223 1.3095 0.69991 4.1543 0.69991 1.874 0 3.9511-0.42898 2.0997-0.45156 3.5899-1.0837zm-14.779-0.92569q0.29351 0 0.45156 0.27093 0.18062 0.27093 0.18062 0.74507 0 0.88053-0.42898 1.3998-1.1515 1.4224-2.3029 2.0772-1.1289 0.65476-2.4158 0.65476-1.9191 0-2.9803-1.1289-1.0612-1.1515-1.0612-3.0706 0-1.1966 0.54187-3.8608l0.83538-4.1317q0.63218-3.1157 0.72249-4.2672-1.4901-0.067733-3.5221-0.067733-1.2192 0-1.7611 0.022578-0.8128 4.1092-1.5353 8.3312-0.24836 1.5353-0.51929 3.5673-0.27093 2.0094-0.36124 3.2512-0.04516 0.65476-0.54187 1.016-0.49671 0.33867-1.1966 0.33867-0.74507 0-1.1515-0.36124-0.4064-0.36124-0.4064-0.94827 0-0.54187 0.15804-1.7836 0.18062-1.2644 0.4064-2.6416 0.24836-1.3772 0.38382-2.3932 0.29351-1.874 0.63218-3.6576 0.33867-1.7836 0.67733-3.4318l0.22578-1.0837q-2.0997 0.24836-3.048 0.8128-0.92569 0.56444-0.92569 1.5353 0 0.79022 0.38382 1.3772 0.11289 0.15804 0.11289 0.4064 0 0.45156-0.49671 0.83538-0.47413 0.36124-1.016 0.36124-0.38382 0-0.63218-0.22578-0.45156-0.38382-0.74507-1.0837-0.29351-0.72249-0.29351-1.6256 0-1.9191 1.3321-3.0706 1.3321-1.174 4.0188-1.7159 2.7093-0.54187 6.9765-0.54187 4.4252 0 8.6699 0.67733 0.69991 0.11289 0.99342 0.47413 0.31609 0.33867 0.31609 0.79022 0 0.67733-0.33867 1.0386-0.33867 0.33867-1.016 0.33867-0.24836 0-0.38382-0.022578l-2.2804-0.29351q-0.09031 1.5804-0.47413 3.2512l-1.3772 6.4572q-0.22578 1.1289-0.22578 1.9417 0 0.94827 0.42898 1.4224 0.45156 0.47413 1.2418 0.47413 0.74507 0 1.445-0.49671 0.72249-0.49671 1.6933-1.6482 0.27093-0.31609 0.6096-0.31609z" stroke-width=".26458"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Snap как-то по своему генерирует path, замененные координаты отличаются от тех, которые нужны http://prntscr.com/l67ja1 (id="fancy-cup") Может быть стоит попробовать tweenMax или smill или свой код написать

Comment: Для простых анимации можно MorphSVG плагин использовать (платный), для сложных анимацию можно делать в AfterEffects и конвертировать в json [плагином](https://airbnb.io/lottie/#/) Или самому писать, простого решения нет

Answer (score 0):

Я поддерживаю коллегу который предложил использовать MorphSVG или GSAP как вариант. Я тоже в свое время сталкивался с подобной проблемой. При морфинге оно там выбирает самый короткий путь который не всегда эстетически правильный. Можно ещё попробовать открыть данный вектор скажем в Illustrator и добавить (или убрать) доп. точки перехода инструментом Перо, возможно это поправит анимацию. Насколько я помню - желательно что б количество точек перехода совпадало с у изначальной и переходящей картинки. [Вот вариант моей работы вообще на `SMIL` без библиотек](https://codepen.io/BlackStar1991/pen/REjMjE)     (Волосы при наведении - морфинг)